# com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I get this error when I am trying to get the current session user from Firebase:

```
  Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.
enter code here
```

It happened to me while testing with my account, so there is no change that the user is invalid or the password has changed.

The code that throws the error is this:

```
   val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
   synchronized(this){
            val currentUser = auth.currentUser  // this line is throwing the error
            ... 
   }
```

What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: I encountered this when testing on an old emulator after I had changed my account's authentication method (from email+pw to Google)